# Creating a dynamic number of output ui elements from dynamic input number of elements

Tags: r, shiny, tidyverse, purrr

I'm trying to reduce some repetitive functions for input and output of renderUI and reactive in order to make more simple the code using purrr.
I found tried to make a version with pmap but it doesn't seem to work.
Could you provide me with some insight or a way to understand how to debug it?

The [repo](https://github.com/ConYel/Fantacy_Craft)

> the table

```
library('tidyverse')
library('data.table')
library("shiny")

Attr_scores <- structure(list(scope = c("Sel1", "Sel2", "Sel3", "Sel4", "Sel5", 
"Sel6", "Sel7", "Sel8", "Sel9", "Sel10", "Sel11", "Sel12", "Sel13"
), A1 = c(14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 18), 
    A2 = c(13, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 13, 14, 16, 14, 15, 17, 12
    ), A3 = c(13, 13, 14, 13, 12, 15, 12, 14, 10, 12, 11, 8, 
    12), A4 = c(13, 13, 13, 12, 12, 11, 12, 10, 10, 10, 11, 8, 
    10), A5 = c(13, 13, 10, 12, 11, 8, 12, 10, 10, 10, 10, 8, 
    10), A6 = c(12, 10, 8, 11, 11, 8, 12, 10, 10, 10, 8, 8, 10
    )), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

> the functions

```
Attr_score_select <- function(y){
  Attr_scores %>% 
    as.data.table() %>% 
    .[y] %>% 
    pivot_longer(-scope) %>% 
    count(value)
}

## change the number of the score you still have
Attr_score_remove <- function(df, score){
    df %>% 
        mutate(n = ifelse(value == score, n-1, n)) %>% 
        mutate(n = ifelse(n == 0, NA, n)) %>% 
        drop_na()  
}
```

> the ui

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Create your Character:"), 
  navlistPanel(
   "Header B",
    tabPanel("Main Attributes",
      sidebarPanel(
     "Attributes",   

        # select the values for each attr
    c("Strength_ui", "Dexterity_ui",
     "Constitution_ui","Intelligence_ui",
      "Wisdom_ui","Charisma_ui") %>% 
          map(~uiOutput(.x))
      ),
      mainPanel( 
       # table with Attributes score
       h4("Select the row with the Attribute scores for your character:"),
       DT::dataTableOutput("table"))
      ),

    "-----",
    tabPanel("Component 4"),
    "-----",
    tabPanel("Component 5")
  )
)
```

> the server working

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(
    DT::datatable(
      data = Attr_scores, 
      style = 'bootstrap', 
      options = list(pageLength = 10),
      selection = "single"))
  Scores <- reactive(Attr_score_select(input$table_row_last_clicked))

  output$Strength_ui <- renderUI({
    #Strength
           selectInput('Strength_1', 
                       label = "Choose Strength score for your character:", 
                       c(Choose='', 
                         as.character(Scores()$value))
           )
  })
  Scores1 <- reactive(Scores() %>%
                        Attr_score_remove(input$Strength_1))
  #Dexterity
  output$Dexterity_ui = renderUI(
    selectInput('Dexterity_1',
                label = "Choose Dexterity score for your character:",
                c(Choose='', as.character(Scores1()$value))
    )
  )
  Scores2 <- reactive(Scores1() %>%
                        Attr_score_remove(input$Dexterity_1))
  #Constitution
  output$Constitution_ui = renderUI(
    selectInput('Constitution_1',
                label = "Choose Constitution score for your character:",
                c(Choose='', as.character(Scores2()$value))
    )
  )
  Scores3 <- reactive(Scores2() %>%
                        Attr_score_remove(input$Constitution_1))
  #Intelligence
  output$Intelligence_ui = renderUI(
  selectInput('Intelligence_1', 
              label = "Choose Intelligence score for your character:", 
              c(Choose='', as.character(Scores3()$value) )
    )
  )
  Scores4 <- reactive(Scores3() %>%
                        Attr_score_remove(input$Intelligence_1))
  #Wisdom
  output$Wisdom_ui = renderUI(
  selectInput('Wisdom_1', 
              label = "Choose 'Wisdom score for your character:", 
              c(Choose='', as.character(Scores4()$value) )
              )
  )
  Scores5 <- reactive(Scores4() %>%
                        Attr_score_remove(input$Wisdom_1))
  #Charisma
  output$Charisma_ui = renderUI(
  selectInput('Charisma_1', 
              label = "Choose 'Charisma score for your character:", 
              c(Choose='', 
                as.character(Scores5()$value))
    )
  )
}
```

> attempt to reduce duplication through tidyverse

```
Scores <- list(
  "Strength_ui",
  "Dexterity_ui",
  "Constitution_ui",
  "Intelligence_ui",
  "Wisdom_ui",
  "Charisma_ui"
) %>% set_names(.)


server <- function(input, output) {

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(
    DT::datatable(
      data = Attr_scores, 
      style = 'bootstrap', 
      options = list(pageLength = 10),
      selection = "single"))
  Scores[["Strength_ui"]] <- reactive(
  Attr_score_select(input$table_row_last_clicked))


  pmap(..1 = names(Scores), ..2 = names(Scores) %>% seq_along(),
    ..3 = c("Strength_1", "Dexterity_1",
      "Constitution_1","Intelligence_1",
      "Wisdom_1","Charisma_1"),
  .f = ~ function(x, y, z){
    output[[..1]] <- renderUI({
      selectInput(..3,
        label = str_c("Choose",str_remove(..1,"_ui") ,
          "score for your character:"),
        c(Choose='',as.character(Scores[[..1]]()$value))
        )
      })

    Scores[[..2+1]] <- reactive(Scores[[..1]]() %>%
                        Attr_score_remove(input[[..3]])) 
    }
  )

}
```

> error message

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3295
Warning: Error in is.data.frame: argument ".l" is missing, with no default
  54: is.data.frame
  53: pmap
  52: server [#13]
Error in is.data.frame(.l) : argument ".l" is missing, with no default
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could try using shiny [modules](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html) .

But I think there is a flaw in the way the available choices are being updated in your code. If the user chooses Charisma first, the choices available for the other attributes won´t be updated. One way to work around this issue would be using a dra-and-drop package, like [sortable package](https://rstudio.github.io/sortable/) or [dragndrop](https://ayayron.shinyapps.io/dragndrop/). Selecting a row would update the drag-and-drop values, and the user would then choose where to place each one of them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I didn't know about the sortable package, it seems could use them directly and not even need to use the previous way, removing completely the problem.It was made this way so as not to remove the values that have been already used. Now I don't know if the question is answered actually as it offers a completely different way of working.

Comment: You can wait a while and see if someone has a better answer. I gave this answer because it sounded the more "clean" answer that dealt with updating the choices problem (although the question did not point this as a problem). If you are curious about accepting answers you can read more about it on meta :)  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work